# ModuleNotFoundError when running unittest with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm writing tests in python's `unittest` and decided to use the module `parameterized` to deal with test parameterization. Now all's fine and dandy when I'm running tests directly with unittest's CLI - simply running `python -m unittest` in root directory launches all the tests as expected. However, I decided for my script to have it's own command flag to run the tests, so when you run, say, `python ./main.py -t [additional arguments for unittest]`, the script itself runs `python -m unittest [additional arguments for unittest]`. For that to happen, I'm using `subprocess.run`. And this also works... well, to some extent. The problem is the following - when I'm using `python -m unittest`, no errors (except for the ones being tested) are raised, but using my script to run the tests raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parameterized'`, along with a few other dependencies my code is using. I'm clueless why is that happening.

To be honest I'm not that familiar with `unittest`, so maybe my approach is the problem, maybe I should handle this in completely different way. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which IDE are you using to run the code other than command line ?

Comment: PyCharm Community, but I was trying to run the script directly from PowerShell as well, with the same results.